# nested_attributes fields not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

In my current rails app, I have a User model which has_one :user_detail. Currently, I cannot get the form to display the fields for the nested attribute unless I already have it seeded with the seeds.rb file.

Here is my User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_detail, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_detail
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :access_level, :first_name, :last_name, :user_detail_attributes
  has_secure_password
end
```

and my UserDetail model

```
class UserDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and my form

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @user] do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.text_field(:name, :placeholder => 'Name')%></p>
  <p><%= f.label(:email) %></p>
  <p><%= f.email_field(:email, :placeholder => 'Your Email')%></p>
  <p><%= f.password_field(:password, :placeholder => 'Choose a password') %></p>
  <p><%= f.password_field(:password_confirmation, :placeholder => 'Confirm Password') %></p>

    <%= f.fields_for :user_detail do |u| %>
      <p><%= u.text_field(:country, :placeholder => 'Country') %></p>
      <p><%= u.text_field(:state, :placeholder => 'State') %></p>
      <p><%= u.text_field(:city, :placeholder => 'City') %></p>
      <p><%= u.text_field(:phone, :placeholder => 'Phone') %> </p>
    <% end %>

  <p><%= submit_tag("Add Owner") %></p>
```

The fields won't show up, until I seed them with this
seeds.rb

```
UserDetail.delete_all
owner1detail = UserDetail.create(:zip => "84770",
                              :country => "US",
                              :state => "Ut",
                              :city => "St. George",
                              :user_id => owner1.id
                             )
```

and I run rake db:seed. Once I do this and I edit an existing user, the fields show up, all filled in. However, when creating a user they don't show up. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the build to my controller like so and it worked

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_user_detail
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to prebuild it.

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @user] do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.text_field(:name, :placeholder => 'Name')%></p>
  <p><%= f.label(:email) %></p>
  <p><%= f.email_field(:email, :placeholder => 'Your Email')%></p>
  <p><%= f.password_field(:password, :placeholder => 'Choose a password') %></p>
  <p><%= f.password_field(:password_confirmation, :placeholder => 'Confirm Password') %></p>

    <% @user.user_detail.build if @user.user_detail.nil? %>

    <%= f.fields_for :user_detail do |u| %>
      <p><%= u.text_field(:country, :placeholder => 'Country') %></p>
      <p><%= u.text_field(:state, :placeholder => 'State') %></p>
      <p><%= u.text_field(:city, :placeholder => 'City') %></p>
      <p><%= u.text_field(:phone, :placeholder => 'Phone') %> </p>
    <% end %>

  <p><%= submit_tag("Add Owner") %></p>
```

Comment: I added it like you said, and now I am getting the error        undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass. Any Ideas?

Comment: it is even giving me this error in the rails console, when I do user = User.new and then user.user_detail.build I get the undefined method 'build'